# MailJet API - Issue in Campaign Creation

Tags: mailjet

This is regarding MailJet API for .NET - https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?csharp#prepare-a-campaign

I get below error when I try to create a Campaign,

> Root = {{
>   "ErrorInfo": "",
>   "ErrorMessage": "Invalid json input: expected ",", but found """ at stream position 133 ...ctsList":"|ContactLis...",
>   "StatusCode": 400
>   }}

Below is code the,

```
var client = new MailjetClient(MjApikeyPublic, MjApikeyPrivate){
    Version = ApiVersion.V3
};
MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest{
    Resource = Campaigndraft.Resource,
}.Property(Campaigndraft.Locale, "en_US")
 .Property(Campaigndraft.Sender, "Mailjet Dv1")
 .Property(Campaigndraft.SenderEmail, "buddhika_jet@outlook.com")
 .Property(Campaigndraft.Subject, "Greetings from Mailjet")
 .Property(Campaigndraft.ContactsList, "10152")
 .Property(Campaigndraft.Title, "Friday newsletter");
response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```

I'm having doubts in the Campaigndraft.ContactsList value that I passed. Considering the official mailjet documentation the parameter should be (Ref - https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?csharp#prepare-a-campaign),

```
.Property(Campaigndraft.ContactsListID, "$ID_CONTACTSLIST")
```

But I cannot find `Campaigndraft.ContactsListID` in the mailjet API version 3 or version 3.1.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem with a help of my friend. Hope this will be helpful to anyone who is developing on top of mailjet API.
So, yes, even though the official documentation (https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?csharp#prepare-a-campaign) directs us to use 'ContactsListID' property of Campaigndraft class,

```
.Property(Campaigndraft.ContactsListID, "$ID_CONTACTSLIST")
```

it is actually not available in he Campaigndraft for some reason.
So, the workaround is to use,

```
.Property("ContactsListID", contactListId)
```

string literal indicating "ContactsListID" value. This is because, Campaigndraft class in mailjet is just a API parameter name mapper and all the properties available in the class indicates the variety of parameters could be used for making API calls.

```
public static class Campaigndraft
{
    public const string Sender = "Sender";
    public const string Status = "Status";
    public const string Subject = "Subject";
    public const string Template = "Template"; 
    //...
}
```

So, string literals can be used instead of all above parameters and any parameter that official mailjet package is missing.
Hope this helps and thanks.